# Why some animation does n't run for some icons when hover on parent element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I created this [website](http://new.travelenter.com/). In this website I have number of tabs that have icon.

Number of this icons, which are `soap-icon`, have animation, but number of icons that are `icomoon-icon` haven't animation. When I check in console I found that animation effect is assigned to this icons, but when I hover on the this icons it runs another  effect.

How to solve this?

[image]

css:

```
.search-box-wrapper.style2 .search-box > ul.search-tabs li > a:hover i:before {
    -webkit-animation: toTopFromBottom 0.35s forwards;
    -moz-animation: toTopFromBottom 0.35s forwards;
    animation: toTopFromBottom 0.35s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at your page and added `line-height: 1em;` and `display: inline-block;` to icons which are not animated, and everything started to work.

```
.icon-insurance:before {
    content: "\e901";
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Maybe it will be more clear if you wrote how your animation method does look like, and which properties do you animate?

Answer (score 1):

I have used `line-height: 1em;` and `display: inline-block;` for Icons, so now it works fine according to your need please use below css in your style.

```
.icon-insurance:before {
    content: "\e901";
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.icon-bus:before {
    content: "\e900";
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.icon-train:before {
    content: "\e902";
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Or you can use below code with single class :

```
.search-box-wrapper.style2 .search-box > ul.search-tabs li > a i:before {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are applying the pseudo classes to the icons container not to the icon itself, the icons are in the :before pseudo element.

if you change:

`[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]`

for

`[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"], [class^="icon-"]:before, [class*=" icon-"]:before`

all your icon- will work.